# Font-weight doing nothing in FF 3.6

Tags: css

I'm trying to [adjust the font weight](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_font_weight.asp) rather than just "bold".  It appears to be doing nothing on Verdana text.  Has browser support for this dropped or something?

```
        <div class='business-hours'>
            Toll free: (866) 528-4930 &middot; Mon-Fri 9-5 EST
        </div>

    #hd .top-nav .business-hours {
        text-align: right;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #9ea3a0;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your CSS and HTML?

Comment: The "font-weight" style definitely **does** do something in Firefox.  Without seeing the code you're using, of course, it's impossible to provide any further advice.

Comment: also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438203/are-all-css-font-weight-propertys-values-useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numeric and other less usual `font-weight` properties (like `semi-bold`, `book` etc.) are supported very poorly across browsers, and AFAIK relevant only if *the font itself* provides support for the given value (i.e. has a explicit `book` or `900` font weight defined). So it's not really a sensible thing to use if consistency is desired.

See [Are all css font-weight property's values useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438203)

And [reference info at the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-weight)

Answer (score 0):

Is it an H1 tag or something? Check that you don't have CSS overwriting your less specific rule. Otherwise Syntax is as follows:

```
<style>
.myboldtext
{
    font-weight: 400;
}
</style>
<span class="myboldtext">This is my bold text</span>
```

400 for regular, 700 for bold.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Even though it says this is my bold text im aware my sample code would be regular! lol

Answer (score 0):

Depending on parent font-styles it can be hard to see that text has in fact been bolded. For example:

```
p {
  font-weight: lightest;
}

p span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

and

```
<p>Hello, <span>world</span></p>
```

In many browsers its actually difficult to see any difference between the bold text and the regular body text.

Instead of just specifying font-weight: bold; try changing it to

```
font-weight: 700;
```

This will tell the browser to render the text with a heavier than even normal bold weight.