# Specific CSS Font Style

Tags: html, css, fonts

quick question, I'm currently trying to style a font to resemble the letters pictured below.  Before I proceed any further I just wanted to be sure there wasn't already a standard, web-safe, font that resembles these letters.  I'm not familiar with font design terminology, so I'm not sure what the technical description of the letters below would be.  Thanks much.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard pre-installed web font (Like Arial, Times ....) out there that is this bold. Under some circumstances, you can [force super-bold text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438203/) using the `font-weight` property but cross-browser support is very shaky, and the font needs to support the boldness.

[Google Web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) has the [Coda](http://www.google.com/webfonts/list?family=Coda&subset=latin) font which seems to come pretty close. Maybe that is an option?

Comment: Thanks for the insight Pekka, I didn't know about Google fonts. It doesn't need to be perfect.  I'll play with it more.  Thanks again.

Comment: @king you're welcome. Note that you are very dependent on Google when using these fonts - as far as I know, there's no way to do a local install, they will always come from Google's servers. That's why I'm always a bit hesitant to use them. But it is the best and easiest way to use free quality web fonts - the other alternative is to buy a font with web support

Comment: You can do a local install just by visiting the font page on the directory and clicking download, then just embed as per usual (fontsquirrel.com has a code generator if you haven't kept up with the IE and android bugs)

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is to use @font-face technology (which Google Fonts also uses) to provide your chosen font to your users. Google it - there's a wealth of material.

The only snag is that you must have a licence that allows you to put the font on the web (but fortunately lots of fonts can be licenced that way now).

Fontsquirrel.com is a good starting point.