# font-weight: 200; not working in Google Chrome and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have this code, and this is only working in IE, the font-weight: 200; that is.

```
#productsSection
{
position: relative;
width: 870px;
height: 277px;
margin-top: 45px;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: 200;
}
```

I am also using font face to import the fonts. Do you guys have any idea what's wrong.

This is the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/zqrXu/ - The headers are in those 3 boxes, you will need to hover over them to see them because they are white atm.

Comment: Please show the full code including the font-face declaration. Does the font have a `200` font weight?

Comment: Support for `font-weight` definitions beyond "bold" and "normal" is spotty at best, it could be that this is your problem (I don't know how this works with font-face fonts, though). Background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438203/are-all-css-font-weight-propertys-values-useful

Comment: @Pekka i've uploaded all the code now: http://jsfiddle.net/zqrXu/

Comment: With all those definitions, you are loading separate fonts, right? Do you have a font file with the target weight?  What does IE do what the other browsers don't, does it actually change the weight of the font?

Comment: @Pekka Yes, IE gives shows me a different font-weight which is the one I want, it's just the others which don't. I don't have a font file specifically for the target weight no, I didn't think it's needed, and I'm not sure I can find it.

Comment: Which version of IE? It looks the same to me between Chrome and IE9