# CSS: what is the difference between "bolder" and "bold" font-weight styles?

Tags: css

What is the difference between `font-weight: bolder;` and `font-weight: bold;` styles?

I never met such style until today, when I found it in our project's CSS file. Result is the same *visually* (tested on Ubuntu 10.10, Firefox 3.6.15).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`bolder` is a [relative font weight](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness):

> The 'bolder' and 'lighter' values select font weights that are relative to the weight inherited from the parent

`bolder` and `lighter`are even part of the [official spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness). How they are interpreted and displayed is up to the browser.

The fact that they appear the same visually is because most browsers don't properly support font weight variations beyond `bold` and `normal`.

Here's a question with background info: [Are all CSS font-weight property's values useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438203/are-all-css-font-weight-propertys-values-useful)

Comment: as I understand these are relational, so bolder should be "more bold" compare to bold

Comment: @sergionni you're right! Edited my answer to point that out more clearly.

Answer (score 32):

First we need to understand the difference between specified weight, computed weight and rendered weight.

For `bold`, the specified weight is "bold", the computed weight is "700" and the rendered weight depends on the font, and the only guarantee is that it won't be lighter than elements with lower computed weights. (i.e. Since "normal" equates to "400", "bold" will never be rendered lighter than "normal" is (though it could be rendered identically.)

For `bolder`, the specified weight is "bolder" and the computed weight is "400" if the container element has a computed weight of less than or equal to 300, otherwise "700"  if the container element has a computed weight of less than or equal to 500, otherwise "900" The rendered weight again depends on the font with the same guarantee.

Since typefaces typically only natively support `normal` and `bold` weights, this often means that `font-weight:bold` and `font-weight:bolder` get rendered identically even if they have different computed weights.

But it doesn't *have* to be the case, even if the font only supports those two weights. In particular, if the container element has a computed weight less than "400", then "bolder" will compute to a weight of "400" and render the same as an element with a specified weight of "normal".

To illustrate this, see this [JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UgAa5/](http://jsfiddle.net/UgAa5/) ¹

```css
p { font-weight:300; font-size:2em }
#scenario1 b { font-weight:bolder; }
#scenario2 b { font-weight:bold; }
```

```html
<p id="scenario1">
    <span>plain</span>
    <b>bold?</b>
</p>    

<p id="scenario2">
    <span>plain</span>
    <b>bold?</b>
</p>
```

---

¹ <sub>Current versions of IE, Firefox, Chrome and Opera all demonstrate this correctly. Older browsers, such as Safari 5.1 do not.</sub>

² <sub>The HTML5 spec says that the `<b>` element should have a default font-weight of "bolder". Firefox and IE do that, but webkit/blink based browsers default to "bold", and normalize.css applies a `font-weight:bold` setting to the `<b>` element for all browsers.</sub>

Comment: The now "current" versions of Firefox and Edge do NOT show these properly.
Interesting how things change. The first line's B is literally unchanged.
Maybe the whole concept didn't catch on, or the relative step isn't big enough to trigger a change in rendering.

Comment: @BloodyRain2k - I think you need to re-read this answer. The point of the demonstration is to show that the word "bold?" in the first line should not be, and is not bolded. Exactly as Edge and Firefox currently do.