# CSS Normalize: bold vs. bolder?

Tags: html, css, bold

What is the difference between the following:

```
b, strong {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

AND

```
b, strong {
   font-weight: bolder;
}
```

I cannot find a proper explanation online... In my CSS Reset I use the second one, font-weight: bolder;

But which one is correct and why?

And to make it even more confusing, I've also seen the following:

```
b, strong {
   font-weight: inherit; 
}

b, strong {
   font-weight: bolder; 
}
```

What is the correct CSS Reset for the font-weight of the b and strong tags in 2021?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#values You can see the difference between bold and bolder by looking at this link. None of the two are wrong. You just choose what you need according to the situation.

Comment: Bold font weight, Same as 700.  bolder,
    One relative font weight heavier than the parent element. Note that only four font weights are considered for relative weight calculation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592868/css-what-is-the-difference-between-bolder-and-bold-font-weight-styles Follow this.