# Bootstrap font-weight utility and black (weight 900) issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, typography

Bootstrap (5.3.1) has it's font-weight utility setup as per the code below. However, using this setup I do not understand how to easily access *font-weight 900* (Commonly called "black"). I tried applying `fw-bolder` to a heading which already displays at "bold" (700) but nothing happens. I assume it should get bumped to 900. Am I seeing a bug, or is this expected behaviour which I am not understanding correctly?

```
"font-weight": (
  property: font-weight,
  class: fw,
  values: (
    lighter: $font-weight-lighter,
    light: $font-weight-light,
    normal: $font-weight-normal,
    medium: $font-weight-medium,
    semibold: $font-weight-semibold,
    bold: $font-weight-bold,
    bolder: $font-weight-bolder
  )
),

//With associated variables:

$font-weight-lighter:         lighter !default;
$font-weight-light:           300 !default;
$font-weight-normal:          400 !default;
$font-weight-medium:          500 !default;
$font-weight-semibold:        600 !default;
$font-weight-bold:            700 !default;
$font-weight-bolder:          bolder !default;
```

Comment: You can understand the meaning of what bolder means [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592868/css-what-is-the-difference-between-bolder-and-bold-font-weight-styles)

Comment: @OMi Shah 0 Thanks. But the parent is the h2 right? Which is set to display at 700. So shouldn't fw-bolder bump that to 900? I have of course made a custom class fw-black as you suggest... but was simply fascinated about how this works.

Comment: I think you missed this line from the above link I shared ``The fact that they appear the same visually is because most browsers don't properly support font weight variations beyond bold and normal.`` Also [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438203/are-all-css-font-weight-propertys-values-useful) answer that can help you understand.