# Font-weight values not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a hyperlink bold in CSS...but not too bold. I use font-weight: 500; which is a little too light, so I use 600 but it just goes to fully bold. Values 700 - 900 are the same too. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438203/are-all-css-font-weight-propertys-values-useful) might be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a different type of font weight, it is important that your font supports this weight type.

If the font doesn't have a 500 or 600 type, it is not possible to use this font weight. The browser will automatically pick the closest value to the font that is available. In this case 600 will change in the 700 which is supported

Answer (score 0):

By default, fonts go either `400`, or normal font weight, or `700`, bold font weight. If you want something in between those or higher/lower, make sure that the font family that you're using has this option built-in.

You can use [google fonts api](https://www.google.com/fonts) for starters and it will tell you what font-weight your desired font family supports, and work your way from there.

One other trick you can pull off is with some tinkering with text-shadow and letter-spacing, to mimic say a 'bolder' font-weight, but thats a last resort solution I guess, since its pretty hard to get it right all across the browser stack.